# SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image when trying to export portion of image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

```
from skimage import filters, measure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy
import imageio
import math
import time
from PIL import Image
# Find contours at a constant value of 10
def grayscale(imgData):
    r=imgData[:,:,0]
    g=imgData[:,:,1]
    b=imgData[:,:,2]
    return  r * 299. / 1000 + g * 587. / 1000 + b * 114. / 1000
loadimg = imageio.imread('cell1.png')
img = filters.gaussian(grayscale(numpy.asarray(loadimg)), sigma=(3.0, 3.0), truncate=3.5)
contours = measure.find_contours(array=img, level=95)
# Display the image and plot all contours found
i = 0
for contour in contours:
    i += 1
    c = contour.astype(int)
    start_row = min(c[:, 0])
    end_row = max(c[:, 0])
    start_col = min(c[:, 1])
    end_col = max(c[:, 1])
    print(numpy.asarray(loadimg))
    ar = numpy.asarray(loadimg)
    slices = ar[start_col:end_col][start_row:end_row]
    export = Image.fromarray(slices)
    export.save("1.png")
```

So I have some code that will identify contours in an image and then put them into a list, so I have a list of the contours of distinct objects, however when I attempt to export the portion of the image covered by the contours, so basically the array that the image is stored in from the index of the first column to last and first row to last, it gives me the following error:

```
/Users/profmonkey07/CA/analyzing/segmentation.py:16: FutureWarning: 'array' is a deprecated argument name for `find_contours`. It will be removed in version 0.20. Please use 'image' instead.
  contours = measure.find_contours(array=img, level=95)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/profmonkey07/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 504, in _save
    fh = fp.fileno()
AttributeError: '_idat' object has no attribute 'fileno'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/profmonkey07/CA/analyzing/segmentation.py", line 29, in <module>
    export.save("1.png")
  File "/Users/profmonkey07/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2240, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/Users/profmonkey07/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 1348, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, _idat(fp, chunk), [("zip", (0, 0) + im.size, 0, rawmode)])
  File "/Users/profmonkey07/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 512, in _save
    e.setimage(im.im, b)
SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

the size of the portion I am trying to export is not larger than the size of the original image, but somehow it Gives this error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: You're doing several things in a single line. Break it up, and show us the full stack trace. Use the REPL to convince yourself that each intermediate result makes sense. (1) Assign `numpy.asarray(loadimg)` to a temp var. (2) On the next line, slice it to contain a subset of pixels. (3) On the next line, pass that into Image.fromarray().

Comment: alright I updated the code and pasted the full stack trace, oh yeah something's wrong, the slices has a length of 0

Comment: Oh, I thought your "export" comment indicated `Image.fromarray()`, but the stack trace reveals it dies in `.save()`. You're assigning a `...` expression to slices. Would you please turn slices into an ndarray with `slices = np.array( ... )` ? Then it should be valid `.fromarray()` input. As it stands, your large image `.size` doesn't match up with the smaller amount of pixels you were hoping to slice out.

Comment: @J_H I rewrote it as this ```slices =numpy.array(ar[start_col:end_col][start_row:end_row])``` however the error is still occuring